# How to get the feature names from polynomialExpansion in pyspark 2.4.0

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

How can I get the feature names of the various combinations that get applied when applying the Polynomial Expansion in `pyspark 2.4.0`.

Here is the Code:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import PolynomialExpansion
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

df = spark\
    .createDataFrame([(Vectors.dense([-2.0, 2.3]),),
                      (Vectors.dense([0.0, 0.0]),),
                      (Vectors.dense([0.6, -1.1]),)],
                     ["features"])
px = PolynomialExpansion(degree=3, inputCol="features", outputCol="polyFeatures")
polyDF = px.transform(df)

spark.createDataFrame(polyDF.rdd.map(lambda row: [row['features']]+row.polyFeatures.tolist())).show()
```

[image]
I need the `column names _2,_3` onwards. Things like `x,x*x,x*y,y,y*y.....` so on!

I need to apply this to a degree of 3 and accordingly know the combination name too in `pyspark`. Please guide if this can be done in a simple way ?

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.0.1/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/PolynomialExpansion.scala) does this using a recursion, so perhaps you could reverse engineer it to get the column names... that said, what's the reason for doing this...?

Comment: Need to find the feature importances wrt to each feature , and each combination is important... May be I don't need to create a df but instead just need the mapping...

Comment: The source code is too complicated to reverse engineer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem, so I decided to try to discover the recursion without actually computing the recursion function.

To figure out the multiplications, i used prime numbers:

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

ex = spark.createDataFrame([(1.0, Vectors.dense(2,3,5,7,11))], ["label", "features"])
```

Then i created the polynomial expansion of degree 3 and applied it:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import PolynomialExpansion

px = PolynomialExpansion(degree=3, inputCol="features", outputCol="polyFeatures")
```

Which gives:

```
ex = px.transform(ex)

ex.show(truncate=False)

+-----+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|label|features              |polyFeatures                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+-----+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1.0  |[2.0,3.0,5.0,7.0,11.0]|[2.0,4.0,8.0,3.0,6.0,12.0,9.0,18.0,27.0,5.0,10.0,20.0,15.0,30.0,45.0,25.0,50.0,75.0,125.0,7.0,14.0,28.0,21.0,42.0,63.0,35.0,70.0,105.0,175.0,49.0,98.0,147.0,245.0,343.0,11.0,22.0,44.0,33.0,66.0,99.0,55.0,110.0,165.0,275.0,77.0,154.0,231.0,385.0,539.0,121.0,242.0,363.0,605.0,847.0,1331.0]|
+-----+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Taking `a=2, b=3, c=5, d=7, e=11` we see the following:

> - 2.0 = a
> - 4.0 = a*a
> - 8.0 = a*a*a
> - 3.0 = b
> - 6.0 = b*a
> - 12.0 = b*a*a
> - 9.0 = b*b
> - 18.0 = b*b*a
> - 27.0 = b*b*b
> - 5.0 = c
> - 10.0 = c*a
> - 20.0 = c*a*a
> - 15.0 = c*b
> - 30.0 = c*b*a
> - 45.0 = c*b*b
> - 25.0 = c*c
> - 50.0 = c*c*a
> - 75.0 = c*c*b
> - 125.0 = c*c*c
>   ...

So for the recursion you have 3 indexes. The first index you iterate on all values, the 2nd index will take values from 1 up to the 1st index (and also take the "empty" index, where you are not choosing any value for the 2nd index) and the 3rd index will take values from 1 to the 2nd index. The code would look like:

```
l = [1, 2.0,3.0,5.0,7.0,11.0]
for i in range(1, 6):
    for j in range(i+1):
        for k in range(j+1):
            print(l[i]*l[j]*l[k])
```

Notice that I had to start the example with the 1, the "empty" index case.